# Pdssql.dll cannot be found

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am attempting to open a Crystal Reports 8.5 document, and when I try to set the database to the Production data server, i get the error "Pdssql.dll cannot be found".  Googling, this is a common problem, but none of the fixes I tried seem to work.

This is a new computer.  I do have SQL Server 2008 client tools installed, but I believe previously I had Sql Server 2005 client tools.

I attempted to install the SQL Server 2005 client tools, but that didn't go through due to me having 2008 installed.  I require 2008 to do my job now.

Everything I search for says this is a 16bit driver, and I need to install the 2005 client tools.  Unfortunately this cannot be done due to me having 2008.  is there some sort of work-around I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had to do if it helps--I had to retire a windows 2000 server so I needed to move a webapp which required Crystal Reports 8.5 onto a new server.

Since I couldn't locate the original installation runtimes (I don't know who developed or even uses this particular webapp) I had to copy all the crystal reports files over to the new server myself and register the required dlls. The crystal reports designer was working except it couldn't seem to make any connection to any of the database servers.

Then I found a folder that I had missed under C:\winnt\crystal which was filled with files such as p2ssql.dll p2lodbc.dll etc... turns out that P2SSQL.DLL is actually Pdssql.dll!

By putting all these dlls into a folder within my system32 path all my database connections within crystal reports were working again!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a DSN in the ODBC administrator? You would have to update the report to use the DSN instead of a "direct" SQL connection, but it should work. ODBC should do it's job and do all the SQL translation (talking to 2008 and just return generic data to the report).

I do not believe a direct connection from Crystal 8.5 to SQL 2008 would be possible though, because the technologies are almost 10 years apart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Download "ntwdblib.dll" and put in

> Windows\sysytem32

if the system 32 bit or in

> Windows \syswow64

if the system 64 bits